# Checking one's closet for somebody

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang

I don't understand the following comment found on YouTube [Bobby Jarzombek](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXpFrexDJ4A):

> Before Portnoy goes to bed, he **checks his closet for** Bobby Jarzombek.

I cannot find any definition of this expression.
Is this a slang?

Let me explain a bit.
Mike Portnoy is known as the best drummer in the world (no doubt here).
The person commented this might think that Bobby Jarzombek is as nearly good as Portnoy.
However, I cannot imagine what he meant.
(Checking his closet ... to find his costume??? Then, ... what?)

Please explain this in Plain English. Thank you.

Comment: It's a cliche that before children can fall asleep they often have to look under their bed and in their closet to make sure there are no monsters. It's probably an allusion to that. If Portnoy feels threatened by Jarzombek, it's a metaphorical analogy. However, I'm only guessing.

Comment: @JasonBassford Ah, I see! Please make it an answer so that I can accept it. I've just found a book called **Tommy's Monster**. It says: _Every night his mom or dad had to check under his bed and in his closet before he would go to sleep._ ... It makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: *"Mike Portnoy is known as the best drummer in the world (no doubt here)."* - There is definitely doubt here. "Best drummer" is a matter of opinion, and trying to pick one "best" across all genres doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that Mike Portnoy is childishly afraid of Jarzombek. This is an allusion to the fact that many [children think there are monsters in their closets](https://www.todaysparent.com/kids/preschool/monsters-in-the-closet/) when they are going to sleep, so either they or their parents may check to comfort them.

The meaning is a little more transparent in the ["Chuck Norris fact"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Norris_facts) "The boogeyman checks for Chuck Norris in his closet every night" (found for example on [Game FAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/928518-super-smash-bros-brawl/42511995), [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/601244-when-the-boogie-man-goes-to-sleep-he-checks-his), and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/OMGrandom/comments/vi5v50/before_the_boogeyman_goes_to_sleep_he_checks_his/) with various wordings), where the roles of the monster and the human are reversed.

Another example:

> David Wright checks for #EricSogard in his closet! #FaceofMLB — [Lanky barber](https://mobile.twitter.com/Hurtssogard/status/439249243044184064)

Comment: check the closet and under the bed for the boogieman.